# Can I prevent a jQuery JSONP client from stealing a security token and passing it on?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, authentication, jsonp

I'm dealing with a custom authentication authorization scheme with a JSONP web service. Because JSONP doesn't support Windows Authentication, the web service -- which does want to authorize against AD -- needs to pass the Windows User ID to the client in an encrypted token, so that it can get passed back during requests.

The initial visit to a web page over HTTPS returns a token cookie as a JavaScript fragment in the ASPX page that gets served to the client:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    the_token = "<base64encoded encrypted token>";
}
```

I know the Windows identity of the user because the Web Application uses Windows Authentication. The cookie consists of `<Windows UserID, TimeStamp, IP-Address of visitor>`.

Now the user clicks on an element that needs to execute a web service that requires authorization. The event handler passes on the token back to the web service as part of the query string passed back to my web service, which lives in a separate web application on the IIS server.

```
$("#theButton").click(function() {
   $getJSON(
       build_url_to_webSvc_with(args,the_token),
       null,
       svc_success).fail(svc_fail);
}
```

The web service now receives the call, decrypts the token, validates that the IP address the call came from is the same as the original requesting IP address, and makes sure the token isn't expired. If authorization passes, the web service performs its service and returns a response, complete with a new token, consisting of `<Same userID that was passed in, new time stamp, IP-Address of visitor>`.

The callback function of the jQuery call is now invoked with the new token, and it gets stored away until the next call to the web service.

```
function svc_success() {
   the_token = arguments[0];    // update with new token from server
}
```

This cycle continues until the token expires or the user closes his window.

My concern is that the token, although encrypted, is plainly visible if the user does "View Source". She can then copy the token and hand it to another user who is capable of logging onto the same machine she's on. Until that token times out, it is vulnerable to this abuse. Should I be concerned about this? If so, what further steps should I be taking to reduce the risk of breach?

Comment: What can you really do about your authenticated users giving their credentials to someone else? What if they verbally share their username/pass? Isn't that the same thing? What if they don't share token at all, and the person just stands behind the user and watches.

Comment: This is basically the same thing that would happen if someone forgot to log out of the machine, correct? someone else who walks up would then be logged in as the previous user *until the token times out*. you could reduce the timeout of the token to reduce the chances of that happening, however that could begin to get annoying for the user.

Comment: I'm concerned with the gold-owners coming back asking "what have you done to mitigate this risk"? At some point, you're going to have to trust the users to behave "securely" (which we all know is really hard to do....)

Comment: @KevinB: not quite, because with the current scheme you could in theory copy the token, log onto _the same machine_ but as another AD user, and use the token to hijack the first session.

Comment: Right, but it's the same scenario is it not? a different user, using another users's token. Since the token is plainly visible to any user who uses the machine, it's really no different whether they got the token by copying it from someone elses or by using their existing session that wasn't logged out.

Comment: @KevinB: the end result is the same, true. Question is, is there anything else I could do to make it harder for the token to be copied here?

Comment: Yes. on unload of the page, send one more request to the server which results in a different token. It's still possible to get the token, but it will be more difficult because when the browser is closed, the token will change one more time, resulting in the one they took from the console no longer being valid.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev: that's what I describe in my question. The AD identity that originally requested the page is encrypted in the cookie. I just don't know how to guarantee that the only entity that sends the token back to me is that same AD identity that first originated the request.